# pandas combine_first but always overwrite

Tags: python, pandas, merge

Can the following be improved upon?

It achieved the desired result of copying values from `df2` to `df1` where the index can be matched. It seems inefficient and clunky.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]], index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(['AB', 'AC']), columns=['X', 'Y', 'Z'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([102, 103], index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(['AC', 'AD']), columns=['Y'])
desired = df2.combine_first(df1).combine_first(df2)

print(df1)
print(df2)
print(desired)

Output:

df1
     X  Y  Z
A B  0  1  2
  C  3  4  5

df2
       Y
A C  102
  D  103

desired
      X    Y   Z
A B   0    1   2
  C   3  102   5
  D NaN  103 NaN
```

The closest I could come to using slicing was

```
print(df1.loc[df2.index, df2.columns])  # This works, demonstrated lhs of below is OK
df1.loc[df2.index, df2.columns] = df2   # This fails, as does df2.values
```

Comment: Why do you need the second `combine_first`? Isn't `desired.equals(df2.combine_first(df1) )== True`?

Comment: Why so it is - I'll revisit my "real" problem and work on a small example that properly illustrates the problem I'm having. (or maybe I'll discover I've overcomplicated things!)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `merge` ??

```
>>df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')
>>df3
       X  Y_x    Z    Y_y
A B  0.0  1.0  2.0    NaN
  C  3.0  4.0  5.0  102.0
  D  NaN  NaN  NaN  103.0
>>df3['Y'] = df3['Y_y'].combine_first(df3['Y_x'])
>>df3.drop(['Y_x', 'Y_y'], axis=1)
       X    Z      Y
A B  0.0  2.0    1.0
  C  3.0  5.0  102.0
  D  NaN  NaN  103.0
```